# Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to dynamically map the keys and values from `list` into `obj`. However, TS gives me an error message:

`Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'`

where I have no idea about what's wrong. Below is the code snippet:

```
interface T {
    // uncomment the next line makes the error go away
    // [k: string]: any
    a: string;
    b?: string;
    c?: number;
}

const obj: T = {
    a: 'something',
};

const list: Array<{
    foo: keyof T;
    bar: string | number;
}> = [
    { foo: 'b', bar: 'str' },
    { foo: 'c', bar: 1 },
];

list.forEach(item => {
    const { foo, bar } = item;

    // The error message comes from the next line
    obj[foo] = bar;
});
```

I notice that if I include the typing `[k: string]: any` into the `interface T`, the error message goes away.

However, I am reluctant to do that because I can then add other key/value pairs into the `obj`, such as `obj.d = 'error'` without TS warning me.

Also, I am curious about why TS would gives me this error message and what is the type `never` thing is all about.

For the `tsconfig.json`, I am using the default values by running `tsc --init` with `version 3.5.1`

Thank you.

Comment: It's [this change](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#fixes-to-unsound-writes-to-indexed-access-types).  It's worried that you're going to write `{foo: "a", bar: 1}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TypeScript 3.5 closed a loophole whereby [index-access writes on unions of keys were not being properly checked](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#fixes-to-unsound-writes-to-indexed-access-types).  If I have an object `obj` of type `T`, and a key `foo` of generic type `keyof T`, then although you can safely *read* a property of type `T[keyof T]` from `obj[foo]`,like `const baz: T[keyof T] = obj[foo]`, it might not be safe to *write* such a property, like `const bar: T[keyof T] = ...; obj[foo] = bar;`  In your code, `foo` might be `"a"` and `bar` might be `1`, and that would be unsafe to write.

The way the loophole got closed: if I read a value from a union of keys, it becomes a union of the property types, as before.  but if I *write* a value *to* a union of keys, it becomes an *intersection* of property types.  So say I have an object `o` of type `{a: string | number, b: number | boolean}` and I want to write something to `o[Math.random()<0.5 ? "a" : "b"]`... what is safe to write?  Only something which works for *both* `o.a` *and* `o.b`... that is, `(string | number) & (number | boolean)`, which (when you fiddle with distributing unions across intersections and reducing) becomes just `number`.  You can only safely write a `number`.

In your case, though, the intersection is `string & string & number`.  And unfortunately, there's no value which is both a `string` and a `number`... so that gets reduced to `never`.  Oops.

---

To fix this case I'd probably refactor this code so that `list` is more narrowly typed, only allowing "matching" `foo` and `bar` properties, and then pass the `forEach` method a *generic* callback where `foo` and `bar` are annotated so that `obj[foo]` and `bar` are seen as identical types:

```
type KV = { [K in keyof T]-?: { foo: K, bar: NonNullable<T[K]> } }[keyof T]
/* type KV = {
    foo: "a";
    bar: string;
} | {
    foo: "b";
    bar: string;
} | {
    foo: "c";
    bar: number;
} */

const list: Array<KV> = [
    { foo: 'b', bar: 'str' },
    { foo: 'c', bar: 1 },
];

list.forEach(<K extends keyof T>(item: { foo: K, bar: NonNullable<T[K]> }) => {
    const { foo, bar } = item;
    obj[foo] = bar; // okay
});
```

The `KV` type does a little type juggling with [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [lookup](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) types to produce a union of all acceptable `foo`/`bar` pairs, which you can verify by using IntelliSense on the `KV` definition.

And the `forEach()` callback acts on a value of type `item: { foo: K, bar: NonNullable<T[K]> }` for generic `K extends keyof T`.  So `obj[foo]` will be seen as type `T[K]`, and you'll assign a `NonNullable<T[K]>` to it, which is [acceptable according to a rule that isn't quite sound but convenient enough to be allowed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769#issuecomment-498428559).

Does that make sense?  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCrIN4FgBQz-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)

Comment: Lol I didn't know that TypeScript is so complicated and smart at the same time...

Comment: Ya, it makes a lot of sense now, thanks for your detailed explanation. I am amazed by these intricacies.

Comment: And if there is anyone wondering about what the "-?:" in type KV does, I found it on [Improved control over mapped type modifiers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#improved-control-over-mapped-type-modifiers), which essentially removes the optional modifier.

Comment: The part that did it for me was `<K extends keyof T>`. Basically creating a type variable that you can reference on both of the object keys, or in my case, two arguments. Awesome!